# Problem outputting HTML table from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, javascript-objects

I'm trying to bring in data from an external json file, and use it to generate a table. I'm running into a problem on line 52 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys' . When I comment out the first 2 async functions, use the sample data in the 'mountains' variable and reference 'mountains' instead of users the html table generates as expected. I think the problem has to do with my 2nd async function but I'm a newbie at a loss. Any help appreciated!

```js
async function getUsers() {
    let url = '../assets/names.json';
    try {
        let res = await fetch(url);
        return await res.json(); 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

async function users() {
    
    let users = await getUsers()                        
 
}


/* let mountains = [
    { name: "Monte Falco", height: 1658, place: "Parco Foreste Casentinesi" },
    { name: "Monte Falterona", height: 1654, place: "Parco Foreste Casentinesi" },
    { name: "Poggio Scali", height: 1520, place: "Parco Foreste Casentinesi" },
    { name: "Pratomagno", height: 1592, place: "Parco Foreste Casentinesi" },
    { name: "Monte Amiata", height: 1738, place: "Siena" }
  ];
  */



  function generateTableHead(table, data) {
    let thead = table.createTHead();
    let row = thead.insertRow();
    for (let key of data) {
      let th = document.createElement("th");
      let text = document.createTextNode(key);
      th.appendChild(text);
      row.appendChild(th);
    }
  }
  
  function generateTable(table, data) {
    for (let element of data) {
      let row = table.insertRow();
      for (key in element) {
        let cell = row.insertCell();
        let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
        cell.appendChild(text);
      }
    }
  }
  
  let table = document.querySelector("table");
  let data = Object.keys(users[0]);
  generateTableHead(table, data);
  generateTable(table, users);
```

Comment: Fetch method use 3 steps, not 2

Comment: @MisterJojo - what? what are the 3 steps?

Comment: `users` is a function ... so `Object.keys(users[0])` won't be what you think ... the issue is that the code to generate the table is run immediately before any of the fetch is done ... you need to run it where you get the data (inside the `async function users()` function) ... and you need call `users()` at some point

Comment: @Bravo 1-fetch(url), 2- then (chose result type) , 3-  then ( use data ) = 3 steps

Comment: ahh, - got it - the function in the question does the first 2 - then the 3rd should be done inside the users function :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `fetch` is asynchronous, you need to process the data only once `fetch` receives it

This should give you an idea

```js
async function getUsers() {
    let url = '../assets/names.json';
    try {
        let res = await fetch(url);
        return res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
async function fakeGetUsers() {
    // fake delay
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));
    // simulate return res.json();
    return [{name:"Monte Falco",height:1658,place:"Parco Foreste Casentinesi"}, {name:"Monte Falterona",height:1654,place:"Parco Foreste Casentinesi"}, {name:"Poggio Scali",height:1520,place:"Parco Foreste Casentinesi"}, {name:"Pratomagno",height:1592,place:"Parco Foreste Casentinesi"}, {name:"Monte Amiata",height:1738,place:"Siena"}];
}
async function users() {
    const users = await fakeGetUsers();
    // here you can use the data
    function generateTableHead(table, data) {
        let thead = table.createTHead();
        let row = thead.insertRow();
        for (let key of data) {
            let th = document.createElement("th");
            let text = document.createTextNode(key);
            th.appendChild(text);
            row.appendChild(th);
        }
    }

    function generateTable(table, data) {
        for (let element of data) {
            let row = table.insertRow();
            for (key in element) {
                let cell = row.insertCell();
                let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
                cell.appendChild(text);
            }
        }
    }

    const table = document.querySelector("table");
    const data = Object.keys(users[0]);
    generateTableHead(table, data);
    generateTable(table, users);
}
users();
```

```html
<table></table>
```